# Whats wrong with this graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=dsjsdchsdch&message=test
```

I used it with the real access token. Its throwing 403.

and oh, i did POST it.

Answer (score 0):

See if the content of the HTTP 403 has an actual API error associated with it.

Comment: it just says 403(forbidden)